# Using Ruby with Nokogiri/Mechanize to scrape data from a webforms params asp

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize-ruby

I am currently trying to scrape data using ruby from a webpage with **Nokogiri** and **Mechanize**. I want to scrape data for to get a list of tenders from next link:
http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/ambientepublico/AP_BusquedaAvanzada.aspx

--Follow this procees---

---

1. open url:
2. Already open, go to the field: **Número**
3. The value from field **Número** is:  **2017-1-37-0-15-cm-011063**
4. Press the first green button: **BUSCAR**
5. Down to see the table with the tender filtered

---

Here my Code:

````html
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'


a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
end


@url='http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/ambientepublico/AP_BusquedaAvanzada.aspx'
@m=Mechanize.new
@payload=''
@body_page = ''
@search_string='2017-1-37-0-15-cm-011063'
@viewstate=""

def set_payload
    {
        'txtGSA' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNumeroAdquisicion'=> '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNombreAdquisicion' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNombreDemandante' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNombreDependencia' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNombreProveedor' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFechaDesde' => '13-02-2017',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFechaHasta' => '13-03-2017',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNombreRubro' => '',
        'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPopupControl1WS' => '0:0:-1:0:0:0:0:0:;0:0:-1:0:0:0:0:0:',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidTotalPaginas' => '0',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidNumeroPagina' => '1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidOrigen' => '0',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidTotalFilas' => '1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidInicioAnterior' => '1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidFinAnterior' => '1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidBloqueInicio' => '1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidMaxFilasPorPagina' => '20',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidMaxPaginasPorListado' => '9',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidCambioBloque' => 'False',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidMostrarEstado' => 'False',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidMostrarMensaje' => 'True',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlPaginacion$hidValoresPorDefecto' => 'True',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIdDependencia' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidNombreDependencia' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIdOrgV' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIdEmpresaVenta' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIdEmpresaC' => '0',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIdOrgC' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidNombreDemandante' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidDependencia' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIDRubro' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidRedir' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidRangoMaximoFecha' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIDProducto' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidIDProductoNoIngresado' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidNombreProducto' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidNombreProveedor' => '-1',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstUnidadCompra' => '',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstEstado' => '0'
    }
end
```

```
@m.get @url do |page|
  page.form_with :name => "aspnetForm" do |search_form|
    @viewstate = search_form.field_with(:name => "__VIEWSTATE").value
    @payload=set_payload
    @m.post(@url,@payload).form_with :name => "aspnetForm" do |search_form_2|
        search_form_2.field_with(:name => "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNumeroAdquisicion").value = @search_string
        submit_button = search_form_2.button_with(:id=>"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnBuscar")
        finish = search_form_2.submit(submit_button)
        @body_page = finish
    end
    puts Nokogiri::HTML(@body_page.body)
  end
end
````

Why the form does not perform the post?
Does not bring post information

Result:

```html
<td class="style1" align="left" valign="top">
  <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNumeroAdquisicion" type="text" value="2017-1-37-0-15-cm-011063" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNumeroAdquisicion">
  <span class="formEjemplos2"><i>Ej.: 2008-1-027-00-08-LP-000274</i></span>
  <div id="divNumLC"></div>
</td>
```

The data send appears on the field, but the tenders table no.

Comment: It's very likely they're using Ajax to update the page and retrieve the data, in which case Mechanize can't help you. Have you checked for that?

Comment: yes i tried and i get the info but i wanted get the data using these gems and using ruby. There is other way to realize this practice? and thanks for you atention.